# LibGDX- How to apply Different Shader to Different Parts(Renderables)..?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I am using libgdx 3dApi for rendering some objects in realtime on browser and android app. I am editing in a test code, its called [ShaderCollectionTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/ShaderCollectionTest.java) of libgdx.

It applies a particular selected shader to a complete instance of the 3d model. I want to apply different shader to different parts(technically "nodes") of a model. Technically speaking, how to apply different shaders to different renderables? I tried many ways, been partially successful sometimes. But still not able to do it robustly and cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one shader per batch.

You need to construct a more complex shader to your batch with sub shaders in it and control which 'section' will be used for each node using shader addtibutes.

Comment: Adding link to the wiki page on how to add custom shader atttributes: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment